# Extracting words with non-ASCII characters by python regular expressions

Tags: python, html, regex

I want to extract some text that contains non-ASCII characters. The problem is that the program considers non-ASCII as delimiters!
I tried this:

```
regex_fmla = '(?:title=[\'"])([:/.A-z?<_&\s=>0-9;-]+)'
c1='<a href="/climate/cote-d-ivoire.html" title="Climate data: Côte d\'Ivoire">Côte d\'Ivoire</a>'
c2= '<a href="/climate/cameroon.html" title="Climate data: Cameroon">Cameroon</a>'
c_list =[c1, c2]
for c in c_list 
    print re.findall(regex_fmla , c)
```

The result is:

```
['Climate data: C']
['Climate data: Cameroon']
```

Notice that The first country is **not** correct, as the series broken at ô, it should be:

```
['Climate data: Côte d\'Ivoire']
```

I searched in StackOverflow, and I found an answer that suggests using the flag re.UNICODE, but it returns the same wrong answer!

How can I fix this?

Comment: The character `ô` does not appear in your regex so, yes, it's a delimiter. `ô` is not an ASCII character, and it's not covered by your `A-z`. (Which incidentally - you may want to know - does also *not* mean "all uppercase and lowercase letters.)

Comment: Why don't you use BeautifulSoup to parse html? It's more light weight than re to parse html

Comment: .. Instead of that complicated regex (where after each next fault you need to squeeze in yet another character), you can search for that closing `"` *only: `"[^"]+\"`. (Just the relevant part.)

Comment: @RadLexus, Thanks, I know that A-z does not include special chars, and my question is how to include all non-English letters to my RegEx?

Comment: @Miguel, Thanks for your comment, but I never tried it before. Is it easier or faster than RegEx?

Comment: Yep, it is... There's already an answer to solve your problem below.

Comment: There is no regular regex code for that, you'd need to add each one separately. Does Python's regex support extended Unicode queries such as `\p{L}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for parsing html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

c1='<a href="/climate/cote-d-ivoire.html" title="Climate data: Côte d\'Ivoire">Côte d\'Ivoire</a>'
c2='<a href="/climate/cameroon.html" title="Climate data: Cameroon">Cameroon</a>'


for c in [c1, c2]:
    soup = bs(c, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.find('a')['title'])
```

for more links (`<a ...>`) use `.findAll()` method:

```
for c in [bightml]:
    soup = bs(c, 'html.parser')
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        print(a['title'])
```

if you need anything that has a `title` attribute:

```
for a in soup.findAll(title=True):
    print(a['title'])
```

Comment: This code solved the problem, but does it have a command similar to "FIndAll" at the regex? i.e. can it extracts all the parts that have "title=" in a long html line?

Comment: Final question, Is there a way to store the results of FindAll to a list, similar to the result of re.FindAll ?

Comment: @MohammadElNesr Don't think BS has this functionality. So just create list yourself and append with `a['title']`s

Comment: @MohammadElNesr or: `[ a['title'] for a in soup.findAll(title=True) ]`

Comment: I have selected your question as bet answer, Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

I also would suggest [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), but it seems you want to know how to include those special chars, you can change your regular expression to this:

```
ex = 'title="(.+?)"'
```

and then:

```
c1='<a href="/climate/cote-d-ivoire.html" title="Climate data: Côte d\'Ivoire">Côte d\'Ivoire</a>'

for x in re.findall(ex, c1):
    print x
```

**Output:**

```
Climate data: Côte d'Ivoire
```

Comment: It returned the following: `["Climate data: C\xc3\xb4te d'Ivoire"]`

Comment: That is the string representation of `Climate data: Côte d'Ivoire`. The same way a newline will be stored as `'\n'`, `'ô'` will be stored as `'\xc3\xb4'`. If you print it, you will see it prints correctly.

Comment: @MohammadElNesr another way to see it is: if you do `"ô" in "Climate data: C\xc3\xb4te d'Ivoire"` it will return `True`

Comment: @CarlesMitjans: isn't that a Python v.2/3 problem? If I recall correctly, no longer an issue in v.3?

Comment: @RadLexus i don't think we can call it a *problem*. It is how python 2.x is made. In python 3 `str` object is now `unicode` object, while 2.7 `str` object is now `bytes` object. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10814498/2148023)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using beautiful soup, but if you would prefer sticking to re:

```
import re

regex_fmla = '(?:title=[\'"])([\w :\':/.]+)'

c1 = '<a href="/climate/cote-d-ivoire.html" title="Climate data: Côte d\'Ivoire">Côte d\'Ivoire</a>'
c2 = '<a href="/climate/cameroon.html" title="Climate data: Cameroon">Cameroon</a>'
c_list = [c1, c2]

for c in c_list:
    print(re.findall(regex_fmla, c, flags=re.UNICODE))
```

I believe the problem that caused the `re.UNICODE` not to work was explicitly defining the alphabet in your expression as `[A-z0-9]`. If we change that to simply `[\w]` then the flag works correctly

Comment: Unfortunately, it also breaks after the o, and returned: 
`['Climate data: C\xc3']`

Comment: That is interesting, it works for me. Perhaps you have some sort of encoding problem - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783079/how-do-i-convert-a-unicode-to-a-string-at-the-python-level