# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa9' python 3

Tags: python, utf-8

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request

imglinks = ["http://www.katytrailweekly.com/Files/MalibuPokeMatt_©Marple_449-EDITED_15920174118.jpg"]

for link in imglinks:
    filename = link.split('/')[-1]
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, filename)
```

It gives me the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa9'

How do I solve this? I tried using `.encode('utf-8')`, but it gives me:

> TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a unicode to a string at the Python level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783079/how-do-i-convert-a-unicode-to-a-string-at-the-python-level)

Comment: @PriyankMehta None of the answers in the question helped. What do I do in my code?

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389572/how-to-fetch-a-non-ascii-url-with-python-urlopen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is not the encoding itself but the correct encoding to pass to `request'.

You need to quote the url as follows:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

imglinks = ["http://www.katytrailweekly.com/Files/MalibuPokeMatt_©Marple_449-EDITED_15920174118.jpg"]

for link in imglinks:
    link = urllib.parse.quote(link,safe=':/') # <- here
    filename = link.split('/')[-1]
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, filename)
```

This way your © symbol is encoded as `%C2%A9` as the web server wants.

The `safe` parameter is specified to prevent `quote` to modify also the `:` after `http`.

Is up to you to modify the code to save the file with the correct original filename. ;)